# How to do this in a better way

Tags: arrays, angular, angular6

Im trying to figure out how to do this a better way without saving a   property and value for tracking purposes. Its my first time working with angular 6. Wondering if we could pipe a bound value. Any Ideas?

```js
public $searchTerms = this.globeGetter.getSearchTermStream().pipe(map(response => {
        return response.map(term => {
            if(term.length > 25) {
                const trimmedSearchTerm = term.substring(0,25) + '...';
                return {
                    value: term,
                    trimmedValue: trimmedSearchTerm,
                    icon: 'search',
                    removable: true,
                };
            } else if(term === "Last 500"){
                return {
                    value: term,
                    trimmedValue: term,
                    icon: 'date_range',
                    removable: false,
                };
            } else {
                return {
                    value: term,
                    trimmedValue: term,
                    icon: 'search',
                    removable: true,
                };
            }
        });
   }));
```

```html
<mat-chip-list>
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let $searchTerm of ($searchTerms | async)" [removable]="$searchTerm.removable" (removed)="removeSearchTerm($searchTerm.value)"  [matTooltip]="$searchTerm.value">
            <mat-icon matSuffix>{{$searchTerm.icon}}</mat-icon>
            {{$searchTerm.trimmedValue}} 
            <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="$searchTerm.removable">cancel</mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Your code is "the best", but you can shorten it, if that's what you ask :

```
...
  .pipe(
    map(response) => response.map(term => term.length > 25 ? { 
      value: term,
      trimmedValue: `${term.substring(0, 25)...}`
      icon: 'search',
      removable: true,
    } : term === "Last 500" ? {
      value: term,
      trimmedValue: term,
      icon: 'date_range',
      removable: false,
    } : {
      value: term,
      trimmedValue: term,
      icon: 'search',
      removable: true,
    })
  )
```

Comment: I want to try to remove trimmedValue from the object because I dont think its needed

Comment: @Karam then simply remove the line from the return object and you're good to go

Comment: I need 2 values to use in the ui, the trimmed value to put in the chip and untrimmed value to put in the tooltip. I was wondering if there was another way of doing instead of saving both values in the obj

Comment: Try the [SlicePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe)

Comment: How would you use it? Sorry if im being annoyong

Comment: `{{ $searchTerm.trimmedValue }}` becomes `{{ $searchTerm.value | slice:0:25 }} `

Comment: but how would that add the ...?

Comment: use CSS for that, `white-space: no-wrap; text-overflow: ellipsis`